# Userscripts possible with highly closured javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures, webpack, systemjs

Okay, so I've been trying to do userscripts for certain websites. However, all of the websites I want to do userscripts for have packing that does not expose anything to me.

For example, [I want to write userscripts for this website](https://tweetdeck.twitter.com) but it doesn't expose enough to me for anything interesting.

Is there any possible way to get through a closure and into it's context? I know Chrome Dev Tools lets you view contexts, but not via code.

Remember, in this scenario, I cannot just simply add something to global context as I do not control the code.

Comment: From a userscript, you might be able to intercept the script loading, rewrite the code to remove the packaging wrapper, and execute it in the global scope so that things become accessible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possible way to get through a closure and into it's context?

If you mean, can you get to the `foo` here:

```
(function() {
    function foo() {
    }
    // ...code using foo...
})();
```

No, you can't, if it's not explicitly made available outside that scoping function.